# Plugin admin page stylesheet doesn't work

Tags: plugin-development

I am trying to style my plugin's admin page. Below is the code is use, but neither the stylesheet nor the script shows up on my page.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'myplugin_admin_init' );
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'myplugin_custom_menu_page' );

function myplugin_custom_menu_page(){
    $page = add_menu_page( 'My Plugin', 'My Plugin', 'manage_options', 'myplugin/myplugin-admin.php', '', plugins_url( 'myplugin/images/icon.png' ), 33 );
     add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts' . $page, 'myplugin_admin_styles' );
     add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts' . $page, 'myplugin_admin_scripts' );
}

function myplugin_admin_init() {
  wp_register_script( 'myplugin-script', plugins_url( 'myplugin/script.js') );
  wp_register_style( 'myplugin-style', plugins_url('myplugin/stylesheet.css') );
}

function myplugin_admin_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'myplugin-style' );
}

function myplugin_admin_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'myplugin-script' );
}
```

Any hints would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to add admin scripts/styles only on your plugin's page:

```
//The add_action to add onto the WordPress menu.
add_action('admin_menu', 'myplugin_custom_menu_page');
function myplugin_custom_menu_page() {
    $GLOBALS['my_plugin_page'] = add_menu_page( 'My Plugin', 'My Plugin', 'manage_options', 'myplugin/myplugin-admin.php', '', plugins_url( 'myplugin/images/icon.png' ), 33 );
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts' );
function my_enqueue_scripts($hook_suffix) {
    if( $GLOBALS['my_plugin_page'] == $hook_suffix ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'myplugin-admin', plugins_url('stylesheet.css', __FILE__) );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'myplugin-admin', plugins_url('script.js', __FILE__) ); 
    }
}
```

In this approach, you don't have to pay attention to screen name. You will always enqueue your scripts for your plugin's page only.

Comment: why did you edit my answer just to add code styles instead of quotes?

Comment: @JMau in this way it is easier to read inline quotation.

Comment: Ok then. Your answer could be easier to implement for @eevaa. Still I think this is quite more logical to use `admin_print_style` even if the codex is telling, for the general case, `use admin_enqueue_scripts`

Comment: This does not work for me either. These are basically just variations of what I did and since I can't see any apparent errors in any of the solutions, the problem must be somewhere else..

Comment: @eevaa I have updated the snippet, there was an error, which has been fixed.